# Socket working only with debug mode react native

Tags: sockets, react-native

My socket emit works properly only on debug mode, when i tried with release APK nothing happened.

Code to connect socket -

```
socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
    transports: ['websocket'],// you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
    forceNew: true,
    jsonp: false
  });

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected!');
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnect!');
  });
```

Code to emit event

```
socket.emit('LIVE_MSG', { msg: "asdfasasdf3" }, (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

I have tried many options with socket connection i.e. timeout, setting and removing jsonp
Also tried with window.navigator.userAgent = "react-native";

But the result is none, socket only emits event when it is in debug mode, gone mad why it is not working with release apk.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue and none of the solutions I've found online have worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't specify url, socket set url as localhost.

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/
"Notice that I’m not specifying any URL when I call io(), since it defaults to trying to connect to the host that serves the page."

(I'm not familiar with socet.io.)